# Replacing words in file using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with over 40k lines inside which I need to replace words, lines using regex. I cannot make it work on my own. Let's say file looks like:

```
test >
test >
test >
test >
```

```
def start():
        file = input("file: ")
        fread = open(file, "r")
        linelist = fread.readlines()
        fread.close()
        fwrite = open(file, "w")
        line = re.sub(".*(?=>)", " ", str(linelist))
        fwrite.write(line)
        fwrite.close()


start()
```

But instead of removing **test** and giving me:

```
>
>
>
```

It gives me

```
  >\n']
```

and no other lines

Comment: You should be using `close()`, not `close`. Methods don't run unless you call them.

Comment: Thanks! But the output remains the same, any other tips?

Comment: `str(linelist)` gives you a string representation of your list, which is why you ended up with square brackets in your output. You could just read your input file as one big string with `fread.read()` instead of a list that you don't really want.

Comment: thanks, that seems to do the job!

Comment: My guess is that the `str` call is in your code because of a previous error message trying to apply the regex to a list. When you get a TypeError, don't just force the type conversion; the first step is to understand why the data is the type that it is, and whether the operation makes sense, then check that the process of generating the data makes sense for the data you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`linelist` is a `list`, you're converting that to string, causing `re.sub` to remove everything before last `>\n]`. When you run `str` on a list you get e.g:

```
In [1]: str([1, 2])
Out[1]: '[1, 2]'
```

That is the main issue. What you need is to iterate over the list and do operation on each line separately and save the modified line.

But there is a better was than doing `spiltlines` on the file object to get all the lines on a single list; as your file is large, this would incur huge memory cost.

Also I would suggest you to use separate files for reading and writing as you're doing operation on each line of the file and then writing back to the same file. If you must use the same file, I would use separate files and then replace (`shutil.move`) the reading one with the writing one once the operations are done.

So overall, a better approach would be to iterate over the file object (as it is an iterator) and do operation:

```
with open('input_file') as in_file, open('output_file', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        modified_line = re.sub(r'^.*(?=>)', ' ', line)
        out_file.write(modified_line)
```

`open` is a context manager so you can use `with` statememnt on it, it has additional benifit of calling `close` on the file object, so you don't need to close them manually.

If your pattern is exactly like the way shown in the example, you can use `str.replace`, no need for Regex:

```
modified_line = line.replace('test ', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Test your regular expression in a "python online regexp tester". RegExp are easy to get wrong. This will tell you if you have it right.

If you just need the output, as opposed to a python script, try notepad++. It supports regexp and can handle 40,000 lines. Many other editors do too. Don't code unless you have to.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answer, regex works tried it now. I do need to code it to make my work a little bit faster as I take a lot of data from API every hour and just need to replace some of the symbols to make the output look cleaner for other program to use.